# After Effects: Add prefix to result of an effect

Tags: javascript, string, integer, prefix, after-effects

I'm trying to get the result from `effect("Slider Control")(1)` and adding a prefix of "£". I've tried the following code:
`effect("Slider Control")(1).val.toFixed(1) + "£"` but it results a possible divide by zero error. Also tried `effect("Slider Control")(1).toString() + '£'` to see if the " or ' would make a difference, but same error.

Can someone help, I only see documentation for converting String to Integer and not the other way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `effect("Slider Control")(1)` returns an After Effects property object, which has various methods, but it is not an actual float or integer like you're expecting, so you cannot call the JavaScript method `toString()` on it.  A solution is to append `.value` to get an actual floating point value out of the property, and then call `toString()` on it.  You can read more about the [After Effects Property attributes and methods](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/aftereffects/cs/using/WS3878526689cb91655866c1103906c6dea-7a0ca.html#WS3878526689cb91655866c1103906c6dea-79f8a).

Here's a working example:
`effect("Slider Control")(1).value.toString() + '£';`

Comment: We did try this as well, and it still came up with a divide by zero error. We've made a workaround now which isn't ideal, but at least it works.

Comment: According to your question, you used `val` instead of `value`, is that correct?